# Xpath - select multiple values (key value pairs)

Tags: xml, xpath

Having this XML:

```
       <slot nodeId='123'>
       <properties>
        <property key="key1" value="value1"/>
        <property key="key2" value="value2"/>
        <property key="key3" value="value3"/>
        ...
        ...
        <property key="keyN" value="valueN"/>
        <property key="keyN+1" value="valueN+1"/>
       </properties></slot>
```

How can I get multiple values from xml, in this format:

For properties:

> key='key1' and key='key10'
>   (multiple conditions)

I want output:

> value1 value10

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can try using XPath `or` operator to combine multiple conditions :

```
//properties/property[@key='key1' or @key='key10']/@value
```

Above XPath return `value` attribute from `<property>` nodes having `key` attribute value equals `"key1"` or `"key10"`.